# What is the diff. between getpid and gettid in c++

Tags: c++, process, pthreads, pid

## getpid() vs gettid()

Please tell me the diff. between getpid and gettid.

Comment: What does it matter so long as they are unique within their own domains?

Comment: [`gettid()` returns the caller's thread ID (TID). In a single-threaded process, the thread ID is equal to the process ID (PID, as returned by `getpid()`). In a multithreaded process, all threads have the same PID, but each one has a unique TID.](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettid)

Comment: Well the thread id you'll get within a process' main thread will be the main thread id. The process id will always be the process id. Did you expect the same value at any point? They're orthogonal things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How pids and tids are stored behind the scenes is implementation dependent, typically through usage of the `pid_t` type.

Usually they are just signed integers.